# Coalesce and max in same query return `Function unknown Coalesce`

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, firebird

I am trying to use `coalesce` with `max()` inside my query, but when I try it, it returns `function unknown coalesce`

This is my query

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(DOCUMENTNUMBER), 0) AS Maxx FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE (DOCUMENTTYPE = 2)
```

And here is the error message:

[image]

When I try same query without `max()` it runs normally.

Answer (score 2):

THIS REFERS TO THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

No quotes around function names;

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(DOCUMENTNUMBER), 0) AS Maxx
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE DOCUMENTTYPE = 2
```

Comment: No sorry, visual studio add it automatically after first run. It doesn't have quotes and I have copied/paste after one more try and forgot to delete quotes, still error

Comment: `coalesce()` was added in Firebird 1.5 (https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-coalesce.html).  That was a long time ago, but perhaps you are using a very old version.

Comment: I am using version 2.1 and as I said, when I delete `max(DOCUMENTNUMBER)` and leave only `COALESCE(DOCUMENTNUMBER, 0)` it works but it list me all rows instead only the max one

Comment: @UProduction . . . You need to figure out where those double quotes are coming from.  They should not be in the query at all.